# socket.io: Disconnect event - 'transport close', 'client namespace disconnect', 'transport error' and 'forced close'

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io

Using socket.io v1.2.1 (only using the "polling" transport), sometimes my clients experience disconnections.

About 50% of the time I get `ping timeout` on my disconnect event callback function, which is reasonable.

Other times, I get `transport close`, `client namespace disconnect`, `transport error` and `forced close`. I did not find any reference to those disconnection reasons in the documentation, and was not able to really understand their meaning from the code.

I want to make sure I handle each disconnection the best way (and maybe prevent them).

Maybe someone can shed a little light about these reasons.

Answer (score 6):

There is no documentation, this is more or less what i can interpret from the code:

`Forced close` - The socket is in closing state

> `Forced close` - https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js

```
function onPacket(packet){
    if ('ping' == packet.type && 'probe' == packet.data) {
      transport.send([{ type: 'pong', data: 'probe' }]);
      self.emit('upgrading', transport);
      clearInterval(self.checkIntervalTimer);
      self.checkIntervalTimer = setInterval(check, 100);
    } else if ('upgrade' == packet.type && self.readyState != 'closed') {
      debug('got upgrade packet - upgrading');
      cleanup();
      self.upgraded = true;
      self.clearTransport();
      self.setTransport(transport);
      self.emit('upgrade', transport);
      self.setPingTimeout();
      self.flush();
      if (self.readyState == 'closing') {
        transport.close(function () {
          self.onClose('forced close');
        });
      }
    } else {
      cleanup();
      transport.close();
    }
  }


Socket.prototype.close = function () {
  if ('open' != this.readyState) return;

  this.readyState = 'closing';

  if (this.writeBuffer.length) {
    this.once('drain', this.closeTransport.bind(this));
    return;
  }

  this.closeTransport();
};
```

The transport where closed (no reason here)

> `Transport close` -  https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js

```
 function cleanup() {
    self.upgrading = false;

    clearInterval(self.checkIntervalTimer);
    self.checkIntervalTimer = null;

    clearTimeout(self.upgradeTimeoutTimer);
    self.upgradeTimeoutTimer = null;

    transport.removeListener('packet', onPacket);
    transport.removeListener('close', onTransportClose);
    transport.removeListener('error', onError);
    self.removeListener('close', onClose);
  }


  function onTransportClose(){
    onError("transport closed");
  }
```

We got a client disconnect packet, so we change socket state to 'closing'

> `Client namespace disconnect` - https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js

```
Socket.prototype.onpacket = function(packet){
  debug('got packet %j', packet);
  switch (packet.type) {
    case parser.EVENT:
      this.onevent(packet);
      break;

    case parser.BINARY_EVENT:
      this.onevent(packet);
      break;

    case parser.ACK:
      this.onack(packet);
      break;

    case parser.BINARY_ACK:
      this.onack(packet);
      break;

    case parser.DISCONNECT:
      this.ondisconnect();
      break;

    case parser.ERROR:
      this.emit('error', packet.data);
  }
};


Socket.prototype.ondisconnect = function(){
  debug('got disconnect packet');
  this.onclose('client namespace disconnect');
};
```

One of the reasons of transport close

> `Transport error` - https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js

```
/**
 * Called upon transport error.
 *
 * @param {Error} error object
 * @api private
 */

Socket.prototype.onError = function (err) {
  debug('transport error');
  this.onClose('transport error', err);
};
```

> https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/transport.js

```
/**
 * Called with a transport error.
 *
 * @param {String} message error
 * @param {Object} error description
 * @api private
 */

Transport.prototype.onError = function (msg, desc) {
  if (this.listeners('error').length) {
    var err = new Error(msg);
    err.type = 'TransportError';
    err.description = desc;
    this.emit('error', err);
  } else {
    debug('ignored transport error %s (%s)', msg, desc);
  }
};
```

It seems like they throw errors to sockets from everywhere, so the only way of find the cause is by reading the error description (not too much information) or looking all their libraries to find what is causing the error.

PD: there are a lot of errors.

Comment: 404 ?

https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/main/lib/socket.ts

Answer (score 1):

Try this code at server side

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pkey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/ssl.key'); //Replace the path of your SSL key
var pcert = fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/ssl.crt');//Replace the path of your SSL cert
var options = {
  key: pkey,
  cert: pcert
};

var app = require('https').createServer(options);

var io = require('socket.io')(app, {'pingTimeout': 180000, 'pingInterval': 25000});
```

Here `pingInterval` is important, Keep it low, I tried various values and found 25 sec is good to keep socket keep pinging before it get timeout.

The main issue is there if within 60 sec there is no ping/pong, then it will disconnect and try to auto reconnect.  Also, I found `pingTimeout` at server side and timeout and client side not able to help to disconnect the socket in 60 sec. It's happening due to chrome latest version 83.

Comment: check this for more info. https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol#difference-between-v3-and-v4

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where too many updates from server to client (around 2000 in a matter of seconds) seemed to cause a forced close of the connection. Sending updates less often solved the problem.

I haven't had a chance yet to find out whether this was caused by socket.io itself, or some firewall/server mechanism. Maybe because flooding the connection between server and client messes up the heartbeat mechanism, although client-side log doesn't show that.

Although the exact cause is not found yet, maybe this can point some people into the right direction to find a solution.

Comment: For us the cause seemed to be that the event loop got "stuck" in specific phase before moving on, therefore taking so long to come back to socket.io stuff that socket.io heartbeat times out and has to reconnect. This is described in https://snyk.io/blog/nodejs-how-even-quick-async-functions-can-block-the-event-loop-starve-io/. Our solution was to process similar type of "phase-actions" in batches tp revent keepeing the event loop too long in 1 phase. It solved our timeout problem. Maybe it can help someone's specific situation that comes to this topic.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately this may happen. Sometimes, as I had misfortune to deal with, it was due to firewall somewhere in between me, server and other client.

For ping timeouts you may try to increase ping interval on server side

```
io = require( 'socket.io' )( httpServer, { pingInterval: 60000 } );
```

Comment: In my opinion, increasing the `pingInterval` value is merely a workaround, not an actual solution. It will cause clients who really did lose the connection seem like their still connected.